# Jest Enzyme testing- button disabled is always truthy so test fails

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-router, enzyme

I am trying to run a test which checks if a button quantity is more than 1 then the minus button is not disabled. But on test this remains disabled, can someone advise where I am going wrong, thanks. I have checked this function works in the browser.

test.file

```
  let wrapper;
  let originalUseState;

  beforeEach(() => {
    originalUseState = React.useState;

    wrapper = mount(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/product/xx59-headphones"]}>
        <Product productData={data.products} />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    React.useState = originalUseState;
  });

  test("When quality of 1 is selected, the - button is disabled", () => {
    let minusButton = locateByTestAttr(wrapper, "minus-button");
    expect(minusButton.props().disabled).toBeTruthy();
    // THIS WORKS //
  });

  test("When the quantity is more than 1, then the minus button is not disabled anymore", () => {
    let minusButton = locateByTestAttr(wrapper, "minus-button");
    let plusButton = locateByTestAttr(wrapper, "plus-button");
    plusButton.simulate("click");
    let quantity = locateByTestAttr(wrapper, "quantity");
    console.log(quantity.text());
    console.log(minusButton.props());
    expect(minusButton.props().disabled).toBeFalsy();
  });
  // THIS DOESNT WORK!! // `
```

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

```
  it("does not call injected onClick if disabled is true", () => {
    const mockOnClick = jest.fn();
    const button = shallow(
      <Button disabled buttonAction={() => mockOnClick} value="send" />
    );
    button.find("button").simulate("click");
    expect(mockOnClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

The thing is, when you trigger the `onClick` event (`plusButton.simulate("click");`) this doesn't update the state of your `minusButton` reference. That's why your assertion fails because it's still seeing the initial state of `minusButton` (which was disabled).

I guess that one way of solving that issue would be to query for that element after the `onClick` event and do the assertions against that element. That way you'd be working with a new reference with the most up-to-date state.

Hope it helps.